# Parameterless function overload

Tags: typescript

How can I specify a parameterless function overload in typescript. I get an error on the following:

```
function f():number; // Error 
function f(string):number; // Okay
function f(x:any):any{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If number of parameters are different for overloads, the additional parameters must be marked as optional. The following will work:

```
function f():number; // Okay now 
function f(string):number; // Okay
function f(x?:any):any{

}
```